# Oracle ROWNUM performance

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

To query **top-n** rows in Oracle, it is general to use ROWNUM.
So the following query seems ok (gets most recent 5 payments):

```
select a.paydate, a.amount
from (
  select t.paydate, t.amount
  from payments t
  where t.some_id = id
  order by t.paydate desc
) a
where rownum <= 5;
```

But for very big tables, it is inefficient - for me it run for ~10 minutes.
So I tried other queries, and I ended up with this one which runs for less than a second:

```
select *
from (
  select  a.*, rownum
  from (select t.paydate, t.amount
        from payments t
        where t.some_id = id
        order by t.paydate desc) a
)
where rownum <= 5;
```

To find out what is happening, I looked execution plans for each query. For first query:

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS   7   5   175
COUNT STOPKEY           
VIEW    7   5   175
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID 7   316576866   6331537320
INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING  4   6
```

And for second:

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS   86  5   175
COUNT STOPKEY           
VIEW    86  81  2835
COUNT           
VIEW    86  81  1782
SORT ORDER BY   86  81  1620
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID 85  81  1620
INDEX RANGE SCAN    4   81
```

Obviously, it is **INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING** that makes first query inefficient for big tables. But I can not really differentiate the logic of two queries by looking at them.
Could anyone explain me the logical differences between two queries in human language?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: id is a bind variable, no (should be :id ?)  if so, what value is used (same?)

Comment: I don't think the `rownum` you're using for the filter in the second version is guaranteed to be the same as it is in the first; think you either need to alias your second query and reference that, or add `order by rownum` in the query against `a`? I doubt this is affecting the speed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in Alex's comment, I'm not sure that your second version is 100% guaranteed to give you the right rows -- since the "middle" block of the query does not have an explicit `order by`, Oracle is under no obligation to pass the rows up to the outer query block in any specific order.  However, there doesn't seem to be any particular reason that it would change the order that the rows are passed up from the innermost block, so in practice it will probably work.

And this is why Oracle chooses a different plan for the second query -- it is logically not able to apply the `STOPKEY` operation to the innermost query block.

I think in the first case, the optimizer is assuming that `id` values are well-distributed and, for any given value, there are likely to be some very recent transactions.  Since it can see that it only needs to find the 5 most recent matches, it calculates that it appears to be more efficient to scan the rows in descending order of `paydate` using an index, lookup the corresponding id and other data from the table, and stop when it's found the first 5 matches.  I suspect that you would see very different performance for this query depending on the specific id value that you use -- if the id has a lot of recent activity, the rows should be found very quickly, but if it does not, the index scan may have to do a lot more work.

In the second case, I believe it's not able to apply the `STOPKEY` optimization to the innermost block due to the extra layer of nesting.  In that case, the index full scan would become much less attractive, since it would always need to scan the entire index.  Therefore it chooses to do an index lookup on `id` (I'm assuming) followed by an actual sort on the date.  If the given `id` value matches a small subset of rows, this is likely to be more efficient -- but if you give an `id` that has lots of rows spread throughout the entire table, I would expect it to become slower, since it will have to access and sort many rows.

So, I would guess that your tests have used `id` value(s) that have relatively few rows which are not very recent.  If this would be a typical use case, then the second query is probably better for you (again, with the caveat that I'm not sure it is technically guaranteed to produce the correct result set).  But if typical values would be more likely to have many matching rows and/or more likely to have 5 very recent rows, then the first query and plan might be better.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks.  @Alex: seems it is better to add `order by rownum` as it adds "SORT ORDER BY STOPRKEY" in exec plan, whereas aliasing `rownum` removes "COUNT STOPKEY" in exec plan. But, as you noted, I haven't seen changes in speed.